# MOSFET Differential Amplifier Bode Plot

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, pspice, bode-plot, differential-amplifier

I've created a MOSFET Differential Amplifier in PSpice, the schematic of which I've attached. However, when doing an AC sweep and adding a trace to do a Bode plot, the graph is a flat line, and I don't quite understand why. Shouldn't there be a negative response as frequency increases?

[image: schematic]

Comment: What model have you used for the MOS? What frequency settings? If the MOS has the default settings, chances are most of them are idealistic zero. Try using a model from the library.

Answer (score 0):

Mae your R1 5,000 ohms.

Your tail current is way too big.